# sending data using localhost iis and php

Tags: php

I am having problems sending data using php. Im following some online tutorial for learning php and am having problems. I fairly certain php is running fine on my iis localhost as I ran a test index.php from localhost and everything came back as it should. I also uploaded the files to a web server where I know php is configured correctly. Im guessing that my problem is with syntax.

The text "your name is" and "You live at" is displayed fine but whatever is submitted is not showing up. I'm fairly certain that the problem is user error caused by yours truly. Any suggestions?

Here is the php file that contains the form:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title><?php echo "Form test";?></title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost/php/phptest1.php" method="post">

      <p>Name:
      <input type="text" id="name" size="30 "value="">
      </p>

      <p>Address:
      <input type="text" id="address" size="30" value="">
      </p>

    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

And here his the php file to receive the data:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo "I have the Info";?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        echo "Your name is: ", $_POST['name'], "<br />";
        echo "You live at: ", $_POST['address'], "<br />";
    ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `<input type="text" id="name" size="30 "value="">` **to** `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30 "value="">` **and** `<input type="text" id="address" size="30" value="">` **to** `<input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" value="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `name` attribute instead of `id`:

```
  <input type="text" name="name" size="30" value="">
```

Comment: Your answer is good, however only to a certain extent. The use of the word **"instead"** should have been replaced by **"in conjunction with"**. The OP can use/keep `id="name"`, while adding/using `name="name"`. `id`, as I stated in my answer, can be used for CSS styling.

Comment: @Fred Not necessarily or do you see something that relies on the `id` attribute?

Comment: I'm merely stating the OP's options.

Comment: @MichaelBrooks Glad that did it for you. I guess I can delete my answer then. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**The reason why your code is not working the way you wanted it to, is that you have 2 errors in your naming convention.**

The form fields need to have the `name="some_name"` added ("some_name" as an example).

**Change**

```
<input type="text" id="name" size="30 "value="">
```

**to:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30 "value="">
```

**and**

```
<input type="text" id="address" size="30" value="">
```

**to:**

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" value="">
```

---

**Full form code:**

```
<html>
<head> 
<title><?php echo "Form test";?></title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost/php/phptest1.php" method="post">

      <p>Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30 "value="">
      </p>

      <p>Address:
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30" value="">
      </p>

    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Added note**: `id` can be kept in the OP's code to be used for styling in **CSS**, which can be kept if needed for styling later down the road.

`id="name"` and `id="address"` can safely be removed.